# Remove preview tab in Crystal Report viewer in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports

I would like to hide the preview tab in the crystal report viewer in my WPF application. A link to the picture is shown below.

**Update:** I would like to remove the tabcontrol "button" on the upper left corner of the window.

I am using Crystal reports version 13. I have tried to find a solution to my problem, including here in stackoverflow, but all the solutions are for different technology.

[image]

Comment: If not preview, what do you want to see on screen then?

Comment: I would like to see the preview page, but not the tabcontrol itself. I would like to get rid of that 0.5 * 2 cm section, hiding it, adn freeing up that line section of the screen.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

please try This

CrystalReportsViewer1.ViewerCore.ReportSource = CRobj;

```
        HidePreviewTabFromCRV();
    }

    private void HidePreviewTabFromCRV()
    {
        //visiual Tree
        var y = GetChild<System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.TabPanel>(CrystalReportsViewer1.ViewerCore);
        y.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    private TargetType GetChild<TargetType>(DependencyObject o)
       where TargetType : DependencyObject
    {
        if (o == null || o is TargetType)
            return (TargetType)o;

        int i = 0;
        if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(o) == 2 && VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(o).GetType() == typeof(TabControl))
            i = 1; // We Arrive Our Destination

        return GetChild<TargetType>(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(o,i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending on Mohand GK's answer, the *GetChild* method fails if you call it before the visual tree is loaded, so to implement this I added the *HidePreviewTabFromCRV* and *GetChild* methods to the XAML code behind, created an event handler in the CrystalReportViewer XAML element for the *Loaded* event:

```
<Grid>
    <crystal:CrystalReportsViewer x:Name="crystalReportViewer" 
                                  Loaded="crystalReportViewer_Loaded" />

</Grid>
```

and then added the HidePreviewTabFromCRV() call to the handler method:

```
private void crystalReportViewer_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HidePreviewTabFromCRV();
}
```

[Image showing tab removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zgh1j.png)